# AngularJS & Rails Recommendation Needed

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I'm currently building a site out of rails, but would like to incorporate AngularJS for the following:

Sort quickly among 2 different types of data ( e.g. clicking different restaurants in a list and then different food categories in a list and seeing all of the results )

Searching through restaurants, food categories and food items.

Identify if "kids" is incorporated into a food item and showing that with a boolean.

After doing a ton of research, I haven't successfully found any great articles / items that fits my needs. Mainly because I would like to use javascript rather than coffeescript as well.  If anyone has any resources or ideas that could help me out, pls send along.

Right now I've looked at the following:

https://www.honeybadger.io/blog/2013/12/11/beginners-guide-to-angular-js-rails
https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-rails-todo-api-part-1

Answer (score 2):

I created an angular filter similar to the one you are describing based off of this fiddle, and with a little help from the thread that it came from. Hope these are of some use to you...

http://jsfiddle.net/rzgWr/19/

[Filter Array Using Checkboxes with AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21058284/filter-array-using-checkboxes-with-angularjs)

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

var uniqueItems = function (data, key) {
var result = [];

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var value = data[i][key];

    if (result.indexOf(value) == -1) {
        result.push(value);
    }

}
return result;
};

function MyCtrl($scope, filterFilter) {
$scope.usePants = {};
$scope.useShirts = {};
$scope.useShoes = {};

$scope.players = [
    {name: 'Bruce Wayne', shirt: 'XXL', pants: '42', shoes: '12'},
    {name: 'Wayne Gretzky', shirt: 'XL', pants: '38', shoes: '10'},
    {name: 'Michael Jordan', shirt: 'M', pants: '32', shoes: '9'},
    {name: 'Rodman', shirt: 'XSXL', pants: '42', shoes: '11'},
    {name: 'Jake Smitz', shirt: 'XXL', pants: '42', shoes: '12'},
    {name: 'Will Will', shirt: 'XXLL', pants: '42', shoes: '12'},
    {name: 'Youasdf Oukls', shirt: 'XL', pants: '38', shoes: '10'},
    {name: 'Sam Sneed', shirt: 'XL', pants: '38', shoes: '10'},
    {name: 'Bill Waxy', shirt: 'M', pants: '32', shoes: '9'},
    {name: 'Javier Xavior', shirt: 'M', pants: '32', shoes: '9'},
    {name: 'Bill Knight', shirt: 'M', pants: '32', shoes: '9'},        
    {name: 'One More', shirt: 'M', pants: '32', shoes: '9'},        
    {name: 'Player One', shirt: 'XXL', pants: '42', shoes: '11'},
    {name: 'Space Cadet', shirt: 'XXL', pants: '42', shoes: '12'},
    {name: 'Player Two', shirt: 'XXXXL', pants: '42', shoes: '12'}
]; 

// Watch the pants that are selected
$scope.$watch(function () {
    return {
        players: $scope.players,
        usePants: $scope.usePants,
        useShirts: $scope.useShirts,
        useShoes: $scope.useShoes
    }
}, function (value) {
    var selected;

    $scope.count = function (prop, value) {
        return function (el) {
            return el[prop] == value;
        };
    };

    $scope.pantsGroup = uniqueItems($scope.players, 'pants');
    var filterAfterPants = [];        
    selected = false;
    for (var j in $scope.players) {
        var p = $scope.players[j];
        for (var i in $scope.usePants) {
            if ($scope.usePants[i]) {
                selected = true;
                if (i == p.pants) {
                    filterAfterPants.push(p);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }        
    }
    if (!selected) {
        filterAfterPants = $scope.players;
    }

    $scope.shirtsGroup = uniqueItems($scope.players, 'shirt');
    var filterAfterShirts = [];        
    selected = false;
    for (var j in filterAfterPants) {
        var p = filterAfterPants[j];
        for (var i in $scope.useShirts) {
            if ($scope.useShirts[i]) {
                selected = true;
                if (i == p.shirt) {
                    filterAfterShirts.push(p);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }       
    }
    if (!selected) {
        filterAfterShirts = filterAfterPants;
    }

    $scope.shoesGroup = uniqueItems($scope.players, 'shoes');
    var filterAfterShoes = [];        
    selected = false;
    for (var j in filterAfterShirts) {
        var p = filterAfterShirts[j];
        for (var i in $scope.useShoes) {
            if ($scope.useShoes[i]) {
                selected = true;
                if (i == p.shoes) {
                    filterAfterShoes.push(p);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }    
    }
    if (!selected) {
        filterAfterShoes = filterAfterShirts;
    }        

    $scope.filteredPlayers = filterAfterShoes;        
}, true);


$scope.$watch('filtered', function (newValue) {
    if (angular.isArray(newValue)) {
        console.log(newValue.length);
    }
}, true);    
}

myApp.filter('count', function() {
return function(collection, key) {
  var out = "test";
  for (var i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {
      //console.log(collection[i].pants);
      //var out = myApp.filter('filter')(collection[i].pants, "42", true);
  }
  return out;
}
});


myApp.filter('groupBy',
        function () {
            return function (collection, key) {
                if (collection === null) return;
                return uniqueItems(collection, key);
    };
});
```

Comment: no problem! glad I could help!
when I was making the filter, I wanted to exclude certain fields from the filter options at one point, like say your menu contains an array of objects named "entrees, appetizers, soups, deserts" and you want to exclude deserts from the filter options, here is a link to a thread I started with an answer on how to do that with a custom Angular filter

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25322035/ng-repeat-filter-negate-string-from-object-angularjs/25322426#25322426